# There were some 20000 people in Chicago demonstration

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I read an article in a newspaper and encountered this sentence given below.

> There were **some** 20,000 people in the Chicago Demonstration.

I searched in the dictionary, and it says "some" is used for unspecified unit. But here the unit is specified i.e. 20,000 people then why is **some** used here?

Comment: That is the first of several definitions given by Lexico, another of which is [**some³**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/some) – (used with a number) approximately. *Some thirty different languages are spoken.*

Comment: I searched on other dictionaries but couldn't find it anyways thank you

Comment: The pile of manure weighed some thirty tons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some** generally means **close to/approximately/about** when it is used before a number.

> There were some (approximately) 20,000 people in the Chicago demonstration.

Comment: Why not give a link to a dictionary definition?

Comment: The sentence lacks the definite article - **in the Chicago demonstration**.

Comment: I considered it as a heading that’s why I didn’t bother to add an article.

Comment: Ok I will edit the question and add the article @ronald sole